# Unable to run flutter commands on my command prompt or vscode terminal

Tags: flutter

Please I need help.
I want to learn flutter for the first time but the problem I'm facing is when I run flutter commands on my cmd or vscode terminal, the terminal get killed immediately after running flutter commands.
Because that I'm unable to create flutter project.
Please how do I fix this problem
PC specs :
Type : Intel® Core™ i5-2540M dual-core processor
Speed : 2.6 GHz
RAM : 4GB
ROM : 118GB
OS : windows

Comment: What OS?  Mac, Windows, Linux?

Comment: Windows operating system please

Comment: Can you run from console `flutter doctor` and add output to the question?

Comment: Please the console does not stay after running the command. The console immediately get killed after running the command therefore I don't see the output

Comment: That's the console dissappers after running any flutter command